# How can I append a variable number of hexadecimal bytes to a file?

Tags: bash

I have the following code

```
printf '\xFF%.s' {1..10} >SomeFile.bin
```

Which lets me write 10 bytes containing 0xFF to a file.

But I would like to write a varying number of bytes to that file. However, curly brace sequences do not work with variables.

Is there a way to do the same operation using a variable instead of the hardcoded 10 repetitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking close to OP's current code:

```
x=10
printf '\xFF%.s' $(seq $x) > SomeFile.bin
```

For ever larger values of `x` the `seq` approach requires ever larger quantities of cpu and memory so at some point it may be worthwhile to look at a looping construct, eg, `awk/for-loop`:

```
awk -v x="9999999" 'BEGIN {for (i=1;i<=x;i++) printf "\xff"}' > SomeFile.bin
```

---

For `x=9999999`:

- `printf/seq` - 48 seconds to run; memory fluctuated with a max of 950+ MB
- `awk/for-loop` - 3 seconds to run; negligible memory usage

**NOTE:** my system: `cygwin` (running in a VM), `GNU bash 4.4.12 (printf builtin)`, `GNU seq 8.26`, `GNU awk 5.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be:

```
n=42
printf '%*s' $n '' | tr ' ' '\377' > file.bin
```

or perhaps

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=$n count=1 | tr '\0' '\377' > file.bin
```

Both methods should be much faster than using `seq`, brace expansion, or `awk`, for large values of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ( time ( mawk2 -v ___='9999999' -v ____='\377' — '
          BEGIN {
              OFS = ____
              if ( ((_+=_+=_^= ORS = "")+_)^_<=(__=+__)) { 
                    print $((NF=__)*!_) 
              } else { _____=+___
                        ___^=_<_
              while(_^_<_____^___^-!!_) {
                  ___+=___ }
                  __=length(___=sprintf("%*s", 
                        int(_____^___^-!!_) + !!_, ORS))  
          
                 gsub(".",____,___)
              _*=____="."
              while((__^=++_)<_____) {  
                  gsub(____,___,___)  } }

             print (__^=_)==_____ \
                    ? ___ \
                    : sprintf("%.*s%.*s", 
                      (_=_____<__) ? _<_:_____-__,
                               ___,_?_____:__,___) }' ) 

   | pvE9 ) | gawk -v ____='\377' -be 'BEGIN { FS = ____
                                               RS = "^$" 
                                       } END { print NF-!_ }' | lgp3

 out9: 9.54MiB 0:00:00 [1.97GiB/s] [1.97GiB/s] [<=> ]

( mawk2 -v ___='9999999' -v ____='\377' -- ; )

0.00s user 0.00s system 35% cpu 0.018 total

9999999
```

> printing `10 million minus 1` copies of `\xFF :: \377` in **`18 milli-seconds`**

benchmark against `perl 5.36.0` - the competition is noticeably slower :

```
out9: 9.54MiB 0:00:00 [1.73GiB/s] [1.73GiB/s] [<=> ]

( mawk2 -v ___='9999999' -v ____='\377' -- ; )

0.00s user 0.01s system 35% cpu 0.019 total

68975d7e7cd4f00255f186f69d9beb65  stdin
```

|

```
out9: 9.54MiB 0:00:00 [1.78GiB/s] [1.78GiB/s] [<=> ]

( perl -le 'printf("%s", "\377" x 9999999)'; )

0.00s user 0.00s system 18% cpu 0.036 total

68975d7e7cd4f00255f186f69d9beb65  stdin
```